# Pandas groupby and selector order

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe with 3 columns:

```
   Criteria Group   Value
0   A       0       0.1
1   B       0       0.2
2   B       1       0.3
3   B       1       0.4
4   A       2       0.5
```

I want to compute for each group the sum of `Values` for items where `Criteria == A` (or this could be a more complex condition on the `Criteria` column). So far I have:

```
df[df.Criteria == 'A'].groupby(df.Group).Value.sum()
```

but this doesn't include groups with no matching items, i.e I get:

```
Group
0    0.1
2    0.5
```

while I want:

```
Group
0    0.1
1    0
2    0.5
```

I've tried reversing the `groupby` and the selector (to group before filtering) but can't figure the correct syntax.

I know I could take what I have then "reinsert" the missing groups with a `0` value but that seems a bit messy so I'm wondering if there is a cleaner/simpler way to do this with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print pd.pivot_table(df, 
                     index='Group', 
                     columns='Criteria', 
                     values='Value', 
                     aggfunc=sum, 
                     fill_value='0')

Criteria    A    B
Group             
0         0.1  0.2
1           0  0.7
2         0.5    0
```

Better format of `DataFrame` with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print pd.pivot_table(df, 
                     index='Group', 
                     columns='Criteria', 
                     values='Value', 
                     aggfunc=sum, 
                     fill_value='0').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()

   Group    A    B
0      0  0.1  0.2
1      1    0  0.7
2      2  0.5    0
```

If you need select only column `A`:

```
print pd.pivot_table(df, 
                     index='Group', 
                     columns='Criteria', 
                     values='Value', 
                     aggfunc=sum, 
                     fill_value='0').rename_axis(None, axis=1).A

Group
0    0.1
1      0
2    0.5
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: This does what I want, great! Thanks for mentioning rename_axis and reset_index, these are useful too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fact that Python's representation of `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A      B
0  0   True
1  0  False
2  1  False
3  1  False
4  2   True

In [13]: df.groupby('A').sum().astype(int)
Out[13]:
   B
A
0  1
1  0
2  1

In [14]: df.groupby('A').sum()
Out[14]:
       B
A
0   True
1  False
2   True
```

Comment: I simplified my example dataset to keep things simple, in reality I have more columns, not all booleans and I'll want to aggregate a third column too. So your answer is technically correct but I was hoping for a more generic solution to filter items after a groupby :).

Comment: @JulesOlléon, help community to help you. Provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JulesOlléon, it's not quite clear what do you want to achieve

Comment: I guess I went too far on the "Minimal" guideline (I thought solving the simpler problem I described would also solve my more complex problem but apparently I oversimplified). I've edited my question to reflect more precisely what I want. Sorry this makes your answer outdated.